# How to access address of an array that is contained in a struct?

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

I am trying to create a program which is reading from an input file using getline.

I have created the following struct

```
struct misc_struct {
   char *buf;
   FILE *some_input_file;
};
```

In my main file I create a buffer and multiple pthreads.

```
char buf[1024];
FILE *some_input_file;
struct misc_struct *pthread_arguments;
...
pthread_arguments = (struct misc_struct *)malloc(sizeof(struct misc_struct));
pthread_arguments->buf = buf;
pthread_arguments->some_input_file = some_input_file;
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, start, (void *)pthread_arguments);
```

Now in my start function:

```
void *start(void *args)
{
    size_t len;
    struct misc_struct *pthread_arguments = (struct misc_struct *)pthread_arguments;
    getline(&args->buf,&len,args->some_input_file);
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately I am crashing at this getline() call. I don't have trouble accessing args->buf but when I need to use the &args->buf for the getline function it crashes with "pointer being realloc'd was not allocated"

What should I be doing differently? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char buf[1024];
:
:
:
pthread_arguments->buf = buf;

getline(&args->buf,&len,args->some_input_file);
```

I suspect `getline()` expects to be able to free and realloc the buffer it is given.

Better to give `getline()` a pointer to a null buffer so it can alloc it as it needs.

```
pthread_arguments->buf = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It makes sense but I also have a second pthread which I need to allow access to the same buffer so I think preallocating the buffer is necessary?

Comment: Do you want the threads to share the buffer? That strikes me as unusual. But if that is the case, then make sure all the calls to getline() get the same char** argument.

Comment: I'm dubious that is what you want. All hell is going to break loose when the threads start writing into the same buffer.